# Using environment Variables in Javascript file when deploying it on Heroku

Tags: javascript, git, heroku, deployment, environment-variables

I have an app written in JS,HTML and CSS which uses an API KEY. I have used environment variables locally to use API KEY. I have deployed it to heroku and while pushing to gitlab, I have added .env to gitignore and now after deployment, map is not visible because it can not access API KEY for maps.
I want to ask how to use environment variables in production (in Heroku deployment)?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use their online dashboard or the CLI to add env vars.

See their docs here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#managing-config-vars

Comment: thanks. But is there any disadvantage of using this approach any security risk etc?

Comment: Depends what you do with the env var, if you show it to the users then yes it isn't secure, but that docs link is how you're meant to handle it and is generally the best security practice.